# automatically flagging duplicate times

Tags: google-sheets, time

**What I am attempting to do**

---

My workers submit their clock in and out times trough a google form, I have it set up to then automatically add up the duration and show it next to the work ID and name. Up until now its been working perfectly but then I discovered that some accidentally submitted there same shift 2 times. I would like an easy way to flag this overlap. I have attempted to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800377/find-total-duration-of-many-overlapping-times?answertab=active#tab-top) but it does not work for AM times. Is there any way I can also detect this for people who work through the night into the morning?

---

Sheet setup
[Current sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m7Ug.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add one when the finish time is less than the start time:

```
=if(query(arrayformula({value(F13:F45+G13:G45),value(F13:F45+H13:H45+(H13:H45<G13:G45))}),
"select count(Col1) where
      Col1<"&value(H13+F13-1/10^4+(H13<G13))&"
  and Col2>"&value(G13+F13+1/10^4)&" label count(Col1) '' ",0)>1,"overlap","ok")
```

(have changed one row to create an overlap)

[image]

If you were just looking for exact duplicates of the shift times, you might have been able to do it more easily with Unique() though.